# How can I directly access a computer's drivers?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to program an app that allows me to play around with my computer's drivers. From what I've heard, I could disguise my phone as another Bluetooth device, but that would require me to root it (which is illegal). Otherwise, I could program a server application on my computer, but I would like everything to be on the phone. So, is there a way to directly communicate with a computer's pre-installed drivers through Bluetooth? If so, could you provide an example of the code?

Comment: Also, why does the first part of my post keep disappearing? I had written "Hello everyone" at the beginning.

Comment: I'm sure you can't do it directly, and you need the computer application, which will do that.

Comment: @GieopDop pleasantries are best left out of questions and answers because they add clutter. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950